# Create states from array object in Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am able to create a state from an object like so...

```
    var stateTest = {
            name: '2',
            views: {
                'video': { 
                  templateUrl: 'templates/2_video.html',
                  controller: 'VideoCtrl'
                },
                'content': {
                  template: '{{content}}',
                  controller: 'VideoCtrl' 
                }
            }
    };

$stateProvider.state(stateTest);
```

but what I need to do is create states from an array. This was my attempt and it is not working.

```
var stateList = [
 {
        name: '3',
        views: {
            'video': { 
              templateUrl: 'templates/3.html',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl'
            },
            'content': {
              template: '{{content}}',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl' 
            }
        }
    },{
        name: '4',
        views: {
            'video': { 
              templateUrl: 'templates/4.html',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl'
            },
            'content': {
              template: '{{content}}',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl' 
            }
        }
    }
];

$stateProvider.state(stateList);
```

Then I thought I needed to try the foreach item approach...

```
var stateList = [
    {
        name: '3',
        templateUrl: 'templates/3.html',
        controller: 'VideoCtrl',
        template: 'content'
    },{
        name: '4',
        templateUrl: 'templates/4.html',
        controller: 'VideoCtrl',
        template: 'content'
    },
];

stateList.forEach(function (item) {
    VideoTest.stateProvider.state(item[0],{
        views: {
            'video': { 
              templateUrl: item[1],
              controller: item[2]
            },
            'content': {
              template: item[3],
              controller: item[2] 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Still no good :( Ideas!?

**------- EDIT ------**
As Craig pointed out in the answer, my array call was jacked up but I also didn't need to call the main module, but rather just place this in a module config like so:

```
VideoTest.config(function($stateProvider) { 


var stateList = [
 {
        name: '3',
        views: {
            'video': { 
              templateUrl: 'templates/3.html',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl'
            },
            'content': {
              template: '{{content}}',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl' 
            }
        }
    },{
        name: '4',
        views: {
            'video': { 
              templateUrl: 'templates/4.html',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl'
            },
            'content': {
              template: '{{content}}',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl' 
            }
        }
    }
];

stateList.forEach(function (item) {
    $stateProvider.state(item.name,{
        views: {
            'video': { 
              templateUrl: item.views.video.templateUrl,
              controller: item.views.video.controller
            },
            'content': {
              template: item.views.content.template,
              controller: item.views.content.controller
            }
        }
    });
});

});
```

Comment: Check this Q&A, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727042/ where you can see even async ($http call driven) assignment of states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with your `forEach` implementation is indexing the `item[0]`. The `item` passed to the `forEach` callback (i.e. arg[0]) is the element itself so indexing this as an array doesn't make sense.

Your data:

```
var stateList = [
 {
        name: '3',
        views: {
            'video': { 
              templateUrl: 'templates/3.html',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl'
            },
            'content': {
              template: '{{content}}',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl' 
            }
        }
    },{
        name: '4',
        views: {
            'video': { 
              templateUrl: 'templates/4.html',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl'
            },
            'content': {
              template: '{{content}}',
              controller: 'VideoCtrl' 
            }
        }
    }
];
```

and state setup:

```
stateList.forEach(function (item) {
    VideoTest.stateProvider.state(item.name,{
        views: {
            'video': { 
              templateUrl: item.views.video.templateUrl,
              controller: item.views.video.controller
            },
            'content': {
              templateUrl: item.views.content.templateUrl,
              controller: item.views.content.controller
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Good catch! That was definitely part of the problem. I'll update the question with the rest.

Comment: ah yes I didn't catch that call of `VideoTest.stateProvider` as being suspect