# AngularJs UI-Router - Page Refresh $state.current is now empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an `Angular` application using `ui-router` and I am having issues whenever I refresh the page. I am using nested views, named views to build the application. Whenever I refresh the page, `ui-router` doesn't reload the current state and just leaves the page blank.

On page load `$state.current` is equal to

```
Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
```

I am reading my navigation from a `.json` file via `$http` and looping through the states. So this is what I can show:

```
stateProvider.state(navElement.stateName, {
    url: navElement.regexUrl ? navElement.regexUrl : url,
    searchPage: navElement.searchPage,   //something custom i added
    parent: navElement.parent ? navElement.parent : "",
    redirectTo: navElement.redirectTo,
    views: {
        'subNav@index': {
            templateUrl: defaults.secondaryNavigation,
            controller: 'secondaryNavigationController as ctrl' //static
        },
        'pageContent@index': {
            template: navElement.templateUrl == null 
                                              ? '<div class="emptyContent"></div>' 
                                              : undefined,
            templateUrl: navElement.templateUrl == null 
                                              ? undefined 
                                              : navElement.templateUrl,
            controller: navElement.controller == null 
                                              ? undefined 
                                              : navElement.controller + ' as ctrl'
        }
    }
});
```

This code gets executed for each item in the nested json object. If there is anything else that would be helpful, let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a question: [AngularJS - UI-router - How to configure dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310) with one answer, which shows how to do that.

> What is happening? On refresh, the `url` is evaluated sooner, then states are registered. We have to postpone that. And solution is driven by `UI-Router` native feature `deferIntercept(defer)`

#### [$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(defer)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider)

As stated in the doc:

> Disables ***(or enables)*** deferring location change interception.
>
> If you wish to customize the behavior of syncing the URL (for example, if you wish to defer a transition but maintain the current URL), call this method at configuration time. Then, at run time, call `$urlRouter.listen()` after you have configured your own `$locationChangeSuccess` event handler.

In a nutshell, we will stop URL handling in config phase:

```
app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
 
  // Prevent $urlRouter from automatically intercepting URL changes;
  // this allows you to configure custom behavior in between
  // location changes and route synchronization:
  $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
 
})
```

And we will re-enable that in .run() phase, once we configured all dynamic states from JSON:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $urlRouter, UserService) {
 
  ...

    // Once the user has logged in, sync the current URL
    // to the router:
     $urlRouter.sync();
 
    // Configures $urlRouter's listener *after* your custom listener
    $urlRouter.listen();
});
```

There is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYJpLcadgk3jpnOci1JS?p=preview) from the linked [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)

Comment: Just a NOTE. I expected that statement in question ***"..I am reading my navigation in from a json file..."*** means you are doing it from loaded `.json`, loaded via `$http`. If not, my answer would not help...

Comment: I am loading a json file through $http calling to a WebApi service, so your answer still applies. Though I added `deferIntercept()` to my config and `sync()` and `listen()` to my run method, I am still running into the same issue.

Comment: I am using the same in real life. 1:1. I would suggest, investigate my plunker and that should help (plus details in the linked Q & A). Or adjust my plunker, and show me what is not working... Because with snippet in your question it is almost the max I can show, I can suggest... Does it make sense?

Comment: The only difference looks to be that your urls contain `^` and mine do not. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: This is just a "reseter" of the url. Without it - children inherit first part from parent. With this sign, children url is starting from the beginning. So, I would doubt this is an issue...

Comment: Debugging the ui-router source now, I'll report back. It seems as if the `check()` function inside the `update()` function is not handling the urls whenever the rules are checked. Could be that my urls are not setup properly on my states. My urls are setup like this: http://pastebin.com/ZHepheCX

Comment: I was able to get my solution pretty much resolved now. It was a 2 part issue, adding the `deferIntercept()`, `sync()` and `listen()` solved one part of the issue. I was also seeing issues if my URL had a trailing slash, so adding `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)` resolved that issue. Thanks for saving me again @RadimKohler!

Comment: @RadimKöhler this solves my issue when refreshing child states. but if i try to access base index '/' only. I get an infinite refresh automatically.

Comment: i have an $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); it should go to a specific state.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how are all your routes.. but if you refresh a page of a child state, you need to pass all parameters of the parents states to be resolved correctly.