# Dynamic view names with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to target dynamic named views in an ng-repeat but can't do so at config phase as views can only be named statically. Is there a way imitate url param matching like `'/path/:param'` but with view names like `views: {'path:param': {...}}` ?

I've tried modifying the state config object at `run()` to see if changing state configuration after `config()` had any effect:

```
rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to, toP, from, fromP) {
  //nope
  if(toP.itemId) {
    to.views['item-'+toP.itemId+'@home'] = to.views['item-:itemId@home'];
    delete to.views['item-:itemId@home'];
  }
}
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkrteD1ls71yd5V10Xub?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This concept would not be working, in general.

> The reason is that **stable, solid** `states` should not be driven by the **`data`** ***(which are very dynamic, changing frequently)***. All `states` and their `views :{}` should be defined first. The `data` *(as a list of items)* should be injected there, consuming already defined states.
>
> - `states` should be defined **once** (even if a bit later, once configuration is loaded via `$http`)
> - `data` could change during the application life-time often, frequently. They should be placed into **`states/views`** - but not drive them

How to load dynamic states dynamically with `$http` *(using the `.run()` phase)*? Check these with full examples and details:

- [AngularJs UI-Router - Page Refresh $state.current is now empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29942522/1679310)
- [AngularJS - UI-router - How to configure dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)
- the doc: [$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(defer)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider)

Small extract from the doc of `deferIntercept(defer)`:

> Disables (or enables) deferring location change interception...

So, we can *(once)* **postpone** the url / location handling... to the moment, when all states are dynamically loaded. But this feature could be used just once.

Well - all that could still not fit into what we want - place some details into the list.

There is a big detail [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902144/1679310), which should give some insight:

[How to replace list item with details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902144/1679310)

Please, have a [look at that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902144/1679310), because there is detailed explanation and working example...