# Autonomous routing on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am working on a project with more 300+ pages based on AngularJS.

Everything is all right, but I'd like to find a way to get rid of those 300+ lines for routing.

Here my thoughts :

1. User goes on url `/settings/company`
2. AngularJS has to load templateUrl at '/template/'+`settings/company`+'.html'
3. Then AnguarJS loads controller `SettingsCompany`+'Ctrl'

Do you think if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ui-router which I would recommend you can create your routes Dynamicly all you need to do is

```
var state = {
 url: someUrl
 template: someHtml
 controller: someController                                                
};

$stateProviderRef.state(TheStatename, state);
```

You obviously need to do that before loading the view. I personally have a static login in my app and after i know which user logged in i load different modules and with this i basicly create the states dynamicly and load the Controller files with lazyload.

Hope this was helpful

Comment: I've never tried ui-router, I am going to try, thanks for the help !

Comment: I forgot to mention you need to add StateProviderRef in you APP.js config

Comment: Like this ? [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7?p=preview) (see app.js file)

Comment: I think it was without config APP.stateprovider = stateproviderref sry cant explain better in my smartphone but you gonna find it with that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727042/angularjs-ui-router-how-to-configure-dynamic-views check the first post in the middle somewhere plunkr is not really smartphone friendlY :(