# Define 'parent' value from param in Angular Ui-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Well, I have this situation:

```
$stateProvider
.state("main", { abtract: true, url:"/main",
  views: {
   "viewA": {
     templateUrl:"main.html"
   }
 }
})
.state("other", {
  parent: ':foo', // Want here the foo param too (:
  //url: '/:foo', // Here it takes de foo param
  views: {
   "viewB@main": {
    templateUrl:"hello.html"
   }
  },
  controller: function($stateParams, $scope, $state) {
   var foo = $stateParams.foo;
  }
})
```

And I call it, like this:

```
<button ui-sref="other({foo: 'main'})">Hello World</button>
```

It is possible to have the `'foo'` param in the `'parent'` property like it was it the `'url'` param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible to have the 'foo' param in the 'parent' property like it was it the 'url' param?

No, it is **not** possible.

State definition must be completely registered before it is used. *(Even if it is loaded lazily with [deferIntercept(defer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310))*

Evaluation of *url* params comes too late...

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. This has take me to make another question => [How to reduce number of 'states' with same 'templateUrl' using Angular Ui-Router](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33107986/2954267)