# How to reduce number of 'states' with same 'templateUrl' using Angular Ui-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, angularjs-routing

Well, I need some help about a routing problem with Angular UI-Roter. Well, actually is not a problem, it's more about to reduce code.

I have three child states:

1. **main.tab1.hello**
2. **main.tab2.hello**
3. **main.tab3.hello**

and they have in common the same `'templateUrl'` : `'hello.html'`

I want to know if is possible to reduce them in only one state, and of course, when I click the button, I don't want to change the URL.

Here is my Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ej7pCo1RRXPTBL6p8dsL

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you dont like states, then use <div ng-if="mystate==2" ng-include="page2.html">

Comment: Yes, it could be, but my question is focused on if it can be done by reducing code, trying to take all these three states in only one state. ¿It is possible? ¿There's a way? ¿Using parameters? That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...Well, actually is not a problem, it's more **about to reduce code**.

In general, I would suggest to use some `array` of *state names* and just iterate that to create all its children:

```
var states = ["main.tab1", "main.tab2", "main.tab3"]

states.forEach(function(parentName){
    $stateProvider
      .state(parentName + ".hello", {
        views: {
        "viewC@main": {
            templateUrl:"hello.html"
        }
       },
    })  
})
```

There is [the updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MBGYTBH4hddmhI7VfQrh?p=preview) with that approach in place

But there are even more sophisticated approaches, profiting from built in feature:

#### [decorator(name, func)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_decorator)

There are working examples with detailed explanation:

- [How to decorate current state resolve function in UI-Router? Current function isn't invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30394658/1679310)
- [AngularJS: How to set one state as a global parent in UI-Router (to use modal as common parts)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32085689/1679310)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It's what I was looking for. Please, can you edit the plunkr and help me to do it with `$stateProvider.decorator`, i can't really catch it.

Comment: A `decorator` is a feature in `UI-Router`, which could help you to reduce code. It could do lot of common stuff at one place for all states. Maybe it is not suitable here *(you should try yourself, really)* but at least the other examples *(links above)* can show what it could do for us. Check also the doc for all available **builder functions**... hope that all helps a bit in future to reduce lot of your code ;)

Comment: Ohh, thanks again ! Now I'm trying to work with `decorator`, but still having some problems to understand. Maybe you can see it: [Setting view's name from decorator - Angular Ui Router](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33112912/2954267)

Comment: A bit later (different time zones, right?;) but .. hope you have the answer ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router sir! ;)

Comment: At the moment I have limited resources... I would suggest to create new Question here. You'll get larger, smarter audience (than just me)... You can later let me a link to it, and if no answer and I will now.. I could come to you later... Makes sense?

Comment: I updated my version of Angular Ui-Router and everything is working as expected. Thank you ! (All in a day's work)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to define your state object, and then simple re-use it when registering the states:

```
var helloState = {
    views: {
        "viewC@main": {
            templateUrl:"hello.html"
        }
    },
};

$stateProvider
    //snip...
    .state("main.tab1.hello", helloState)
    .state("main.tab2.hello", helloState)
    .state("main.tab3.hello", helloState);
```

Taking it one step further you could define a service that exposes all of these state definitions. If you need to override any properties you can use `angular.extend` on the state object.

Comment: Interesting idea ! Thanks for your answer.