# Dynamic routes from server data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have some nested routes defined dinamically:

```
var res = [
  {i:1,title:"title 1"},
  {i:2,title:"title 2"},
  {i:3,title:"title 3"},
  {i:4,title:"title 4"}
];

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider,$httpProvider) {
    // other routes [...]
    angular.forEach(res, function(d) {
        $stateProvider.state('nested.q' + d.i, {
           url: '/' + d.i,
           template: '{{d.i}} - {{d.title}}'
       });
    });  
});
```

`var res` should be retrieved in ajax from the server, I'm not sure how to accomplish that in this step of the angular workflow (earlier that any service or controller loads).

**EDIT based on @Radim Köhler answer I tried this code, what's wrong with this? the routes simply aren't registered:**

```
var  $stateProviderRef; // is this global var used like you thought??
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider,$locationProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('about', {
        url: "/about",
        templateUrl: "/partials/about.html"
    })
$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: false});
$stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

});

app.run([ '$rootScope','$http', '$urlRouter',
    function ($rootScope, $http, $urlRouter)
    {
        $http
            .get("/api/remoteStates")
            .success(function(data)
            {
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key)
                {
                    console.log(value)
                    $stateProviderRef.state(value.name, {
                        url: value.url,
                        template: value.template
                    });
                });
                $urlRouter.sync();
                $urlRouter.listen();
            });
    }]);
```

/api/remoteState response:

```
[
  {
    "name": "state1",
    "url": "state1",
    "template": "<h1>state1</h1>"
  },
  {
    "name": "state2",
    "url": "state2",
    "template": "<h1>state2</h1>"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXTEND:

Based on extended question, there is [**a working example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q6x9q9bvRbRyAQ4NIutV?p=preview). The JSON was adjusted like this:

```
// api/remoteStates.json
[
  {
    "name": "state1",
    "url": "/state1",
    "template": "<h1>state1</h1>"
  },
  {
    "name": "state2",
    "url": "/state2",
    "template": "<h1>state2</h1>"
  }
]
```

And this is almost unchanged state registration

```
// script.js - first part CONFIG phase
app.config(function ($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
     .state('about', {
        url: "/about",
        templateUrl: "partials/about.html"
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/about');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: false});
    $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;
});

app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

and the run part

```
// script.js - RUN phase
app.run([ '$rootScope','$http', '$urlRouter',
    function ($rootScope, $http, $urlRouter)
    {
        $http
            .get("api/remoteStates.json")
            .success(function(data)
            {
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key)
                {
                    console.log(value)
                    $stateProviderRef.state(value.name, {
                        url: value.url,
                        template: value.template
                    });
                });
                $urlRouter.sync();
                $urlRouter.listen();
            });
    }]);
```

Check that all [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q6x9q9bvRbRyAQ4NIutV?p=preview)

ORIGINAL part
Check this Q & A:

[AngularJS - UI-router - How to configure dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)

As documented here

> #### [$urlRouterProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider)
>
> **The deferIntercept(defer)**
>
> Disables (or enables) deferring location change interception.
>
> If you wish to customize the behavior of syncing the URL *(for example, if you wish to defer a transition but maintain the current
>   URL)*, call this method at configuration time. Then, at run time, call
>   **`$urlRouter.listen()`** after you have configured your own `$locationChangeSuccess` event handler.

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYJpLcadgk3jpnOci1JS?p=preview)

Wee need to do that in config phase ***(postpone execution)***

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

    // Prevent $urlRouter from automatically intercepting URL changes;
    // this allows you to configure custom behavior in between
    // location changes and route synchronization:
    $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/other');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: false});
    $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;
});
```

Then, we get a data from server($http) in a **`run`** phase and once new dynamic states are created.. just call **`sync`**

```
app.run([ '$rootScope','$http', '$urlRouter',
  function ($rootScope, $http, $urlRouter) 
  {
    $http
      .get("myJson.json")
      .success(function(data)
      {
        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) 
        { 
          var state = {
            "url": ...
            "parent" :  ...
            "abstract":  ...
            "views": { ... }
          };

          angular.forEach(value.views, function (view) 
          {
            state.views[view.name] = {
              templateUrl : view.templateUrl,
            };
          });

          $stateProviderRef.state(value.name, state);
        });
        // Configures $urlRouter's listener *after* your custom listener            
        $urlRouter.sync();
        $urlRouter.listen();
      });
}]);
```

Comment: thanks, it looks like it breaks the normal $stateProvider behaviour, I have those dynamic routes, but I have also several static routes defined with $stateProvider..

Comment: It is working together.. static and dynamic. Just.. until the server data are loaded, and sync is called.. the UI-Router is waiting. So, even the dynamic url will be working as expected. I would say, that you should play with this solution.. and it should fit to your needs ;)

Comment: I've just realized that since my server data are not-so-lightweight (about 15 extra states and their templates). It would be way better a lazy load technique for states and controllers (maybe with ocLazyLoad), what's your opinion? anyway very thanks your answer solve a problem in another application of mine.

Comment: oc lazy load is good way to go. Also, start to check Angular2 and brand new approach with NgModules, which are out of the box (native angular 2 solution) ready for lazy loading. BTW I do use the above approach.. to load about hundred states based on data coming from server. I do not have any issue with performance. Hope it hleps a it. Good luck with UI-Router ;)

Comment: I extended my answer, used your question details and created plunker. Please, observe it, and I am sure you will gladly see how easy it is ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router sir...