# Bootstrap ui-router states programmatically

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm working with angular 1.

I want to load some data from server before ui-router bootstrapping all the states.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I suggest you look at [ui-router wiki page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), but I don't think it is possible

Comment: ui-router includes the ability to resolve data before it loads the view. RTFM

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in this Question: [AngularJS - UI-router - How to configure dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)  and mostly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310) you can get the answer.

The point is to use a feature of `UrlRouterProvider`  - **`deferIntercept()`**

> **[The deferIntercept(defer)](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider)**
>
> Disables (or enables) deferring location change interception.
>
> If you wish to customize the behavior of syncing the URL (for example,
>   if you wish to defer a transition but maintain the current URL), call
>   this method at configuration time. Then, at run time, call
>   `$urlRouter.listen()` after you have configured your own
>   `$locationChangeSuccess` event handler.

*Full description including working example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)*