# AngularAMD + ui-router + dynamic controller name?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-amd

I'm trying to write a generalized route in my application and resolve the view and controller names on the fly based on the route params.

I have the following code that works:

```
$stateProvider.state('default', angularAMD.route({
    url: '/:module/:action?id',

    templateUrl: function (params) {
        var module = params.module;
        var action = module + params.action.charAt(0).toUpperCase() 
                            + params.action.substr(1);

        return 'app/views/' + module + '/' + action + 'View.html';
    },

    controller: 'userController',
}));
```

However, I'm unable to figure out a way to resolve the controller name dynamically. I tried using `resolve` as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808213/Developing-a-Large-Scale-Application-with-a-Single), but ui-router seems to handle resolve differently than angular-route.

Any pointers?

**EDIT**: I've already tried using `controllerProvider` but it doesn't work for me (for instance, the following code just returns a hard coded controller name to test whether it actually works):

```
controllerProvider: function () {
    return 'userController';
}
```

Gives me the following error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'userController' is not a function, got undefined
>   `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/ng/areq?p0=userController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a link to [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dlXHDf?p=preview).

### solution

We need two features of the UI-Router:

- resolve *(to load the missing pieces of js code)*
- controllerProvider (see cites from documentation below)

#### angularAMD - main.js definition

This would be our main.js, which contains smart conversion controllerName - controllerPath:

```
require.config({

    //baseUrl: "js/scripts",
    baseUrl: "",

    // alias libraries paths
    paths: {
        "angular": "angular",
        "ui-router": "angular-ui-router",
        "angularAMD": "angularAMD",

        "DefaultCtrl": "Controller_Default",
        "OtherCtrl": "Controller_Other",
    },

    shim: {
        "angularAMD": ["angular"],
        "ui-router": ["angular"],
    },

    deps: ['app']
});
```

#### controllers:

```
// Controller_Default.js
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.controller('DefaultCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "from default"; 
    });
}); 

// Controller_Other.js
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.controller('OtherCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "from other";
    });
});
```

#### app.js

Firstly we would need some method converting the param (e.g. id) into controller name. For our test purposes let's use this naive implementation:

```
var controllerNameByParams = function($stateParams)
{
    // naive example of dynamic controller name mining
    // from incoming state params

    var controller = "OtherCtrl";

    if ($stateParams.id === 1) {
        controller = "DefaultCtrl";
    }

    return controller;
}
```

#### `.state()`

And that would be finally our state definition

```
$stateProvider
    .state("default", angularAMD.route({
        url: "/{id:int}",
        templateProvider: function($stateParams)
        {
            if ($stateParams.id === 1)
            {
                return "<div>ONE - Hallo {{title}}</div>";
            }
            return "<div>TWO - Hallo {{title}}</div>";
        },
        resolve: {
            loadController: ['$q', '$stateParams',
                function ($q, $stateParams)
                {
                    // get the controller name === here as a path to Controller_Name.js
                    // which is set in main.js path {}
                    var controllerName = controllerNameByParams($stateParams);

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    require([controllerName], function () { deferred.resolve(); });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }]
        },
        controllerProvider: function ($stateParams)
        {
            // get the controller name === here as a dynamic controller Name
            var controllerName = controllerNameByParams($stateParams);
            return controllerName;
        },
    }));
```

Check it here, in this [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dlXHDf?p=preview)

### documentation

As documented here: [$stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider), for a `state(name, stateConfig)` we can use `controller` and **`controllerProvider`**. Some extract from documentation:

#### controllerProvider

...

**`controller`** *(optional)* stringfunction

> Controller fn that should be associated with newly related scope or the name of a registered controller if passed as a string. Optionally, the ControllerAs may be declared here.

```
controller: "MyRegisteredController"

controller:
"MyRegisteredController as fooCtrl"}

controller: function($scope, MyService) {
$scope.data = MyService.getData(); }
```

**`controllerProvider`** *(optional)*   function

> Injectable provider function that returns the actual controller or string.

```
controllerProvider:
  function(MyResolveData) {
    if (MyResolveData.foo)
      return "FooCtrl"
    else if (MyResolveData.bar)
      return "BarCtrl";
    else return function($scope) {
      $scope.baz = "Qux";
    }
  }
```

...

#### resolve

**`resolve`** *(optional)*  object

> An optional `map<string, function>` of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. **If any of these dependencies are promises**, the **router will wait** for them **ALL to be resolved** before the controller is instantiated...

I.e. let's use **`controllerProvider`**:

> *... to resolve the controller name dynamically...*

*In case, that you managed to get here, maybe you'd like to check another similar solution with RequireJS - [angular-ui-router with requirejs, lazy loading of controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754025/1679310)*

Comment: I already tried that (should have mentioned it in my question). I get "[ng:areq] Argument 'userController' is not a function, got undefined" if I use controllerProvider.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is on my corporate network which doesn't allow me to post to plunker. However, I just did happen to stumble across this: https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD/issues/117 - so looks like it's not just me :)

Comment: OK, I created one for you ;) with UI-Router we can do almost anything ;) Enjoy it

Comment: w00t! This works for me. Thank you! :) You have a wonderful week!

Comment: Hey, I'm just wondering if you guys know how to dynamically load a template HTML file rather than just have the HTML inline.

Comment: Wonderful solution!.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This breaks if you do a form submit, redirect to a new page, and then go back to it. The controller then gets lost and it cannot find it. You will get "controller is undefined" error.