# can we load controller in angular.js dynamically using require.js OR any other way?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

can we load controller in angular.js dynamically using require.js  OR any other way ?
Kindly help me on this.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you. The best way I found is using [angularAMD](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD)

Also check out [ui-router-extras](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras) for a great sample that loads views, states and controllers dynamically using angularAMD and ui-router-extras Future States feature.

- [Demo](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/future/index.html)
- [Source](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/tree/gh-pages/example/future)

Finally, there is a good example here on StackOverflow about loading a controller with a dynamic *name* as well:
[AngularAMD + ui-router + dynamic controller name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465289/angularamd-ui-router-dynamic-controller-name)