# ControllerProvider in UI-router results in error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I have a `ui-router` `StateProvider` and need to pick between controllers & views based on external data, so I used `TemplateProvider` and `ControllerProvider`.

If I only had the `TemplateProvider` it all works fine, but when I add the `ControllerProvider` I get this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.1/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%Object
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/Angular/1-angular.js:80:12)
    at assertArg (http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/Angular/1-angular.js:1577:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/Angular/1-angular.js:1587:3)
    at annotate (http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/Angular/1-angular.js:3417:5)
    at invoke (http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/Angular/1-angular.js:4096:21)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/Angular/1-angular.js:4129:23)
    at http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/Angular/1-angular.js:8320:28
    at compile (http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/AngularUIRouter/angular-ui-router.js:3897:28)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/Angular/1-angular.js:8081:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:48510/Scripts/Vendor/Angular/1-angular.js:7593:11)
```

Looks like some `undefined` `serviceName` possibly (it says got object, but it looks like it's `undefined` but I'm not great at debugging `AngularJs`)

Here is my code:

```
.state('abstractParent.childState', {
    url: '/childState',
    controllerProvider: ['myService', function (myService) {
        return myService
          .isSpecificMember()
          .then(function (result) {  //this returns a promise of a bool.
            if (result.data) {
                return 'SpecificController';
            } else {
                return 'GeneralController';
            }
        })
    }],
    templateProvider: ['myService', '$templateFactory',
     function (myService, $templateFactory) {
        return myService.isSpecificMember().then(function(result) {
            if(result.data)
            {
                return $templateFactory.fromUrl('SpecificView');
            } else {
                return $templateFactory.fromUrl('GenericView');
            }
        })
    }],
    resolve: {
        thing: ['thingService', function (thingService) { 
            //this is only used in one of the controllers.
            return thingService.getThing();
        }]
    }})
```

**EDIT**

Changes based on Radim Köhlers answer

```
    .state('abstractParent.childState', {
        url: '/childState',
        resolve: {
            controllerName: ['myService', function (myService) {
                return myService.isSpecificMember().then(function (result) {  //this returns a promise of a bool.
                    if (result.data) {
                        return 'SpecificController';
                    } else {
                        return 'GeneralController';
                    }
                })
            }],
            thing: ['thingService', function (thingService) { //this is only used in one of the controllers.
                return thingService.getThing();
            }]
        },
        controllerProvider: ['controllerName', function (controllerName) {
            return controllerName;
        }],
        templateProvider: ['myService', '$templateFactory', function (myService, $templateFactory) {
            return myService.isSpecificMember().then(function(result) {
                if(result.data)
                {
                    return $templateFactory.fromUrl('SpecificView');
                } else {
                    return $templateFactory.fromUrl('GenericView');
                }
            })
        }]
        })
```

New error:

```
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: controllerNameProvider <- controllerName
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.1/$injector/unpr?p0=controllerNameProvider%20%3C-%20controllerName
        at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (1-angular.js:80)
        at 1-angular.js:3930
        at Object.getService [as get] (1-angular.js:4077)
        at 1-angular.js:3935
        at getService (1-angular.js:4077)
        at Object.invoke (1-angular.js:4109)
        at angular-ui-router.js:3465
        at processQueue (1-angular.js:12901)
        at 1-angular.js:12917
        at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (1-angular.js:14110)
```

**SOLUTION**

This needed at least version `0.2.14` of `angular-ui-router.js`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point is, that `controllerProvider` simply must return **object** representing the `controller` or `string` *(its name)*

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

> **`stateConfig.controllerProvider`** *(optional)* function
>
> Injectable provider function that returns the actual **controller** or **string**.

So, we cannot return promise...

But there is a solution:

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/svc8KMF4woMFrTamFfwC?p=preview)

We can use built-in feature **resolve** - to do the async stuff, and make `controllerProvider` a hero - by consuming it:

```
  resolve: {
    controllerName: ['$stateParams', '$timeout','$q', 
        function ($stateParams, $timeout, $q)
        {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
           $timeout(function(){ 

            deferred.resolve('MyLazyRevealedCtrl');

          },250);
          return deferred.promise;
        }],

  },
  controllerProvider:['controllerName', function (controllerName)
  {
      return controllerName;
  }],
```

What we can see is simplified example with just a timer (playing role of async **`.then()`**). It waits a while and returns resolved controller name.

The **`controllerProvider`** then ***(once all is resolved)*** just takes that result, and returns it as a string.

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/svc8KMF4woMFrTamFfwC?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, I assumed it could accept promise just like the TemplateProvider. Your solution sounds fine, but I guess I could just add the controller name in my template as I'm basing it on the same logic. but in cases where we are not, your solution is great.

Comment: I would say it is great to see how you play with UI-Router ;) great. There are some limitations, but if we can solve them easily... ;) Here is more complex example of how to use *"really dynamic controller resolver"* http://stackoverflow.com/q/27465289/1679310... Enjoy UI-Router, sir!

Comment: Weird, I can see this working in your example, but I'm getting a unknown provider for controllerName `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: controllerNameProvider <- controllerName`

Comment: This means, that resolve in your code returns **'controllerName'** in your case... instead of `'SpecificController'`... could you check that? I would guess that this would be just a typo...

Comment: No I think it is a problem with the injection into the `ControllerProvider`, I do my resolve the same way you do, resolve to a property named `ControllerName`. Then I inject that `ControllerName` property into the provider, I never hit the breakpoint inside the `ControllerProvider`.

Comment: I think this is a version issue with ui-router, I have 0.2.13, you have 0.2.14 in your plunkr and if I downgrade there it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I will update the UI-router version for my project and see, if it does solve it you might want to add **needs version 0.2.14 or higher** to the answer

Comment: I'd say... the up to date version is the way... leaving you...hope that all helped a bit ;)

Comment: Can confirm, this must have been a feature added in the newest version, works all fine now. Thank you for all the help.