# How to make URL simplier in UI-router

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state

Here is my `$stateProvider` configuration:

```
.state('itemDetail', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/itemDetail/general/:itemid',
    controller: 'ItemDetailsController',
    templateUrl: './partials/itemDetails.html'
})
.state('itemDetail.general', {
    url: "",
    controller: 'ItemDetailsController',
    templateUrl: "./partials/itemDetails.General.html"
})
.state('itemDetail.file', {
    url: "/file/:itemid",
    controller: 'ItemDetailsController',
    templateUrl: "./partials/itemDetails.File.html"
})
```

The user can look at item using `#/itemDetail/general/96045` and can click the link to look at file attachments.  Now it is work but URL for files now is `#/itemDetail/general/96045/file/96045`.

Is it possible to have  URL for files as `#/itemDetail/file/96045`?

Comment: Setting `abstract` to `true` in your `itemDetail` state will always prepend any children states with the `url` defined in that state (i.e. `/itemDetail/general/`). You could instead have `url` in the `itemDetail` state set to `/itemDetail`, and `url` in the `itemDetail.general` state set to `/general/:itemId`. If doing this, you will obviously have to adjust your template markup links.

Comment: Yes, it works.  But in this case it works if I go to the view using `ui-sref`, but the `$stateParams` is undefined if I open `itemDetails/general/100` direct in the browser. In this (unworking) case the ItemController called only once (for one view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would go with *one* parent and only **`one child`** state. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uy7FrEpUQhvqIu40h3yM?p=preview)

This will be the new one child state `itemDetail.type`:

```
.state('itemDetail', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/itemDetail',
  controller: 'ItemDetailsController',
  templateUrl: 'partials/itemDetails.html'
})
.state('itemDetail.type', {
  url: "/:type/:itemid",
  controller: 'ItemDetailsController',
  templateProvider: ['$stateParams', '$templateRequest', 
    function($stateParams, $templateRequest) {
      var url = "partials/itemDetails.General.html";
      if($stateParams.type === "file"){
          url = "partials/itemDetails.File.html"  
      }
      return $templateRequest(url);
  }],
})
```

We are using here `$stateParams.type` to decide which template to load *(and also `$templateRequest` to profit from angula built in caching)*

And this will be the calling html:

```
<a ui-sref="itemDetail.type({type:'general', itemid:1})">
<a ui-sref="itemDetail.type({type:'file', itemid:22})">
```

The url will now look as expected

check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uy7FrEpUQhvqIu40h3yM?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but if I undertood correctly it will be work only if all states have one (and the same) Controller.  But it is not my case (in general).

Comment: Surprisingly we can use the same trick for controller - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30260604/1679310 ... coool ;) *(I just used your snippet.. but UI-Router built in features are ... bloody fantastic)*

Comment: Thanks. But I have one more question :).   I need to have itemid in `partials/itemDetails.html`.  If I set `url: '/itemDetail'` for `itemDetail` state - I will not have this variable in my controller for this view.  What is the good way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Great to see that progress ;) Because we are on the right track with this approach... Well we can move that params into parent state.. it is not an issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/542Rc0kRaXfVkBswAJpC?p=preview BUT It wil mean that even parent will be reloaded when any params is changed ;) good luck with UI-Router sir

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be you need to give state as

```
.state('itemDetail.file', {
        url: '/{itemId}',
        controller: 'ItemDetailsController',
        templateUrl: 'partials/itemDetails.html'
    })
```

Comment: I have `Error: Could not resolve '.file' from state 'itemDetail'` in this case

Comment: i think you just make url in this format
url: '/{itemId}