# Can I access $stateParams from a state's view object?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Using, Angular UI-Router, I have the following state:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('blog.article', {
      url: '/:slug',
      template: '<article></article>',
      views: {

      }
    });
```

I'm parsing the article slug in the url, which becomes available in `$stateParams`. However, I would like to target a parent state's named `ui-view` using this slug, is it possible to set the name of custom view to the slug in my case? So views object looks something like this:

```
views: {
   'stateParams.slug': {/* etc */}
}
```

Comment: I'm really at a loss at what you're trying to do. The `views` object in a call to `$stateProvider.state` sets up nested views for that state. The `:slug` is available in `$stateParams` for every nested view in that state - *injected to view's controller*. The parent view of `blog` won't see any `$stateParams` because it's a fixed path e.g. `/`.

Answer (score 0):

> ...However, I would like to target a parent state's named ui-view using this slug, **is it possible to set the name of custom view** to the slug in my case?

No. The `views : {}` setting is static, not dynamic.

But there are still dynamic parts like controllerProviders, templateProviders, resolvers etc. And you should think about handling your logic there

```
views: {
   'viewName': {
       templateProvider: ...
       controllerProvider: ...
       resolver: ...
   }
}
```

see:

- [Angular and UI-Router, how to set a dynamic templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868796/1679310)
- [ControllerProvider in UI-router results in error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30259668/1679310)
- [Angular ui.router reload parent templateProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29785692/1679310)
- [Angularjs ui-router abstract state with resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27168835/1679310)