# How to group routes using angular ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-route

How to group routes in ui-router?

For example, i have following routes in my app

```
#/products/p1
#/products/p2
#/products/p3
```

One way of defining states will be,

```
.state(‘products.p1’)
.state(‘products.p2’)
.state(‘products.p3’)
```

But i am looking for something like followings, Is it possible to do so?

```
.state(‘products’,{
  ‘p1’ : {},
  ‘p2’ : {},
  ‘p3’ : {} 
})
```

Comment: Please post your code, your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be managed by parameters

```
#/products/p1 // parameter p with value p1
#/products/p2 // still parameter p with value p2
#/products/p3 // value is p3
```

state can have it defined like this

```
.state('products', {
    url: "/products/:p
    ...
})
```

Comment: Is't possible to assign different controllers based on :P value?
I have few static pages and i want to group them under single brach??

Comment: Yes... it is possible, but .. won't be better to have the same controller and different stuff in services? anyhow, here you can see how to do that  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27466890/1679310 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/30259668/1679310