# Properly loading controller path in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a complex Angular app and I'd like to know if there is a proper way to load a controller file path in an ui-router.

Currently, I load every controllers file in the main view like this : `<script src="myCtrl.js"></script>`.

I know that I can use ui-router like this :

```
 $state provider
    .state('state1'), {
       url: '/state1',
       views : {
           'area1' : {
                        templateUrl: 'myView.html',
                        controller: 'myCtrlName' // change this to load the file ?
            },
            ... // some other area + templateUrl here
       }
    }
```

But it's used to load the controller name, not its path. I tried to find a way by using `load` or `file` functions instead, but it didn't make it.

Do you have any idea ?

Edit : Maybe it can help you to know thatmy goal is to load my controller file out of the html view in order to simplify the html file and simply add/delete controllers in the app.

Comment: *Try to observe this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27754025/1679310 or that http://stackoverflow.com/a/27466890/1679310*

Comment: `.state('state1'),` should be `.state('state1', {`

Comment: So if i understand your case, you have one controllers per file ? In this case you have declared one module by controllers file so inject module in app.js and add your controller.

Comment: @RadimKöhler I read that question. Isn't there an easier way ?

Comment: check this out man https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: @Arhyaa Honestly I am not sure. But I would say NO, because all the runtime of angular, including UI-Router is expecting services, controllers to be loaded.. but maybe I missed some brand new feature... My way in fact is: load all controllers... their code (minimized) should not be an issue in fact...

Comment: @carton I have one module to declare every controller, and it seems to work. I use a file per controller, and they're not in the same folders.

Comment: @generalgmt Thx man, but I've already read it. It didn't help me in the way I'm searchin' for

Comment: If one module declavere every controller just add this module in your app.js and use controller: 'myCtrlName' (like your sample)

Comment: *@Arhyaa, please, take is as a hint. Maybe I missed some brutal enhancment of angular ;) just a hint how to do that all with RequierJS ;)*

Comment: @carton I'm already doing this. What I want to simplify is the controller.js path load :)

Comment: @RadimKöhler I've spent a week looking for another way, and I found nothing at all. It doesn't cost anything to try ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Radim Köhler and these questions [angular-ui-router with requirejs, lazy loading of controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627806/angular-ui-router-with-requirejs-lazy-loading-of-controller/27754025#27754025) + [AngularAMD + ui-router + dynamic controller name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465289/angularamd-ui-router-dynamic-controller-name/27466890#27466890), I'll try to use RequireJS.

Thanks a lot guys :)