# Start Angular.js route-segment or ui-router after all translations are loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

Is there any way, how to start ui-router or route-segment just after translateProvider loads its translations?

I'm using pascal prechts translate filter together with bind once {{:: }} notation. On localhost it works pretty good, but when I test it on remote server, bind once will remove watchers sooner than strings are translated.

So I was wondering if there is some way how to delay routing a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check the native, built-in feature:

#### [$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(defer)](http://%20angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_deferintercept)

> Disables (or enables) deferring location change interception.
>
> If you wish to customize the behavior of syncing the URL (for example, if you wish to defer a transition but maintain the current URL), call this method at configuration time. Then, at run time, call `$urlRouter.listen()` after you have configured your own `$locationChangeSuccess` event handler.

Check some similar issues:

- [AngularJS - UI-router - How to configure dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)
- [can we add dynamic states to $stateprovider with already existing states in ui-router angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29422780/1679310)

In one of these links, [observe this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HL9zaSlApLNMzN6OQlgg?p=preview), where this feature is used like this:

Stop and wait in **`.config()`** phase:

```
.config(['$urlRouterProvider' ...,
    function($urlRouterProvider, ...) {

      // defer execution in config phase
      $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
      ...
```

Later in **`.run()`** phase turn the url hanlding on

```
.run(['$urlRouter' ...,
  function($urlRouter...) {
    ...
    $http
      .get("modules.json")
      .success(function(data) {
        
        // do some stuff
        // re-enable UI-Router url stuff
    
        $urlRouter.sync();
        $urlRouter.listen();
    
      });
```

Comment: I have found few more plunkers, like this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/VLS45S0TYSlwZVJ3Wg4g?p=preview where it is used.. It works for small $timeout like 20'000ms but when I put there 60'000ms routing won't start.. Also I didn't found anything like this for route-segment-provider which we are using in our app..

But for small timeouts (or in our case loading initial files) it will be good enought.. thank you

Comment: Great, ... if that helped anyhow. Enjoy amazing UI-Router, Honzo ;)