# Ionic - Adding states dynamically

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile application using *Ionic* framework. I get a `JSON` file containing the template and it's controller. The server will push data once there's data in `JSON` format. The problem is adding the states dynamically, and I have read that it's only possible at the config time.

Please tell me if there's a way to do this through a controller which will only be responsible of receiving and setting the new state and that will also receive the `JSON` and from it create the new state.

The help is highly appreciated!

**Edit**

I have found ui-router-extras (http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future), but I don't know how to make it work for my application.

Suppose a controller gets the JSON using ***$http*** where the `JSON` looks like:

```
{
  'name':'preview',
  'template':'<h1>Hello</h2>'
}
```

How to add this state in this controller?

Comment: Sounds like ui router extras future states

Comment: @ChrisT I have edited the question, if you can help me with it please by telling me exactly how to do it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are some simliar Q & A:

- [AngularJS - UI-router - How to configure dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24727042/1679310) - this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)**
- [Start Angular.js route-segment or ui-router after all translations are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30455792/1679310)
- [Angular - Dynamically Choose Starting State](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30477922/1679310)

Which shows, that UI-Router is shipped with a great feature:

#### [$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(defer)](http://%20angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_deferintercept)

> Disables (or enables) deferring location change interception.
>
> If you wish to customize the behavior of syncing the URL (for example, if you wish to defer a transition but maintain the current URL), call this method at configuration time. Then, at run time, call `$urlRouter.listen()` after you have configured your own `$locationChangeSuccess` event handler.

There are some working plunkers [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqyrXRhwJwNv6VUjGPYd?p=preview) or [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HL9zaSlApLNMzN6OQlgg?p=preview),

showing that in **`.config()`** phase we will stop url router:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // States, which we know about from beginning
        // could be declared "statically"
        $stateProvider
          ... 
        // here we say STOP
        $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
    }
])
```

Later, in **`.run()`** phase, we will 1) configure states via $http 2) enable url routing

```
.run(['$urlRouter', '$timeout', '$state',
  function($urlRouter, $timeout, $state) {

    $http
      .get("modules.json")
      .success(function(data) {
        // here we can use some JSON to configure $stateProvider

    // in example we can use $timeout to simulate that 
    $timeout(function(){

      // here we turn all on again...
      $urlRouter.sync();
      $urlRouter.listen();

      // there could be some decision, driven by $http load
      // we just use some state as default target
      $state.go("parent.child");
    }, 1000)
    ...
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqyrXRhwJwNv6VUjGPYd?p=preview) or [there](http://plnkr.co/edit/HL9zaSlApLNMzN6OQlgg?p=preview)

Comment: This solution assumes that I will update the states on startup of the app because you're using "run" function. I want the solution to be just like a $http service, for example, that I can use in the controller whenever I want to retrieve the new states and add them to the available states.

Comment: That is part of the examples I showed you, check this answer and its plunker http://stackoverflow.com/a/24730459/1679310... Anytime you can add new states. It will work fully - as shown in plunker. The only difference (when not using $urlRouter.sync()) is that on refresh, that won't work... because that was not called yet