# Angular JS-Reload Dynamic States

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-ui-router, refresh

I'm loading some states from a JSON file, all states get loaded and become  available ,but when reloading or searching the URL in other browser window, I can't access anymore the dynamic states ( I get redirected to default page), It seems to be the execution flow; When  page redirect, the JSON is not loaded because is loaded after the index.

Any Idea about solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solution could be found here *(with detailed descriptions)*:

- [Start Angular.js route-segment or ui-router after all translations are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30455792/1679310)
- [AngularJS - UI-router - How to configure dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)

the point is a feature:

#### [$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(defer)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_deferintercept)

> Disables (or enables) deferring location change interception.
>
> If you wish to customize the behavior of syncing the URL (for example, if you wish to defer a transition but maintain the current URL), call this method at configuration time. Then, at run time, call `$urlRouter.listen()` after you have configured your own `$locationChangeSuccess` event handler.