# UI-router dynamic `abstract` property

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Well I am trying to set the `ui-router's` `abstract` property to true dynamically, so that I can avoid unauthorized access by the user to that route. I could only think of that way to achieve that goal. Here's the demo route.

```
.state('project', {
    abstract: {{value}},
    url: '/users',
    templateUrl: 'views/configuration/index.html',
    },
```

I want that once the angular app loads, all such routes becomes `abstract-true` whose access should be denied to the user. Please help me out in achieving this task and learning something new.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is dynamic state load by using [$urlRouter.sync()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#urlroutersync):

```
$urlRouter.sync();
$urlRouter.listen();
```

I think [this example in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HL9zaSlApLNMzN6OQlgg?p=preview) will help you to sort things out

---

```
var $stateProviderRef = null;

 // some value = {/* ... */}

 var getExistingState = $state.get(value.name)

  var state = {
     "url": value.url,
     "parent": value.parent,
     "abstract": value.abstract,
     "views": {}
   };

   angular.forEach(value.views, function(view) {
     state.views[view.name] = {
       templateUrl: view.templateUrl,
     };
   });

   $stateProviderRef.state(value.name, state);
 });        

 $urlRouter.sync();
 $urlRouter.listen();
```

---

Took demo from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428174/1631379)

Comment: Thank you sir, but I had already seen this option, but couldn't satisfy my need as my routes contain different resolve properties. They all don't have the same format.